# гуляет высота input

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу понять почему при разных масштабах страницы input и button постоянно меняют свою высоту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

КОД КНОПКИ

```
background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 179px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  height: 43px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 23px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
```

Код input

```
padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #ea7300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 485px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ea7300;
```

Comment: должен помочь box-sizing: border-box

Comment: это из-за бордера кнопки такое. У инпута бордера ведь нет. И лучше ровнять высоту паддингами.